# Raster NA Error in R - Error in { : task 5 failed - "0 (non-NA) cases"

Tags: raster, r, error, nodata, esri-ascii-raster

I'm trying to conduct a landscape genetic analysis through the R Package [*ResistanceGA*](https://github.com/wpeterman/ResistanceGA) on some environmental rasters. However, I keep running into the error `Error in { : task 5 failed - "0 (non-NA) cases"` when my rasters are being passed through the algorithm. I've had no issues to date with any of the other datasets that I've used, however, this dataset was sourced externally. This leads me to believe that it is something to do with the raster itself, and not the package. All rasters are in .asc format and have been converted from GeoTIFFs.

Data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CBV50t8Gpu3wiWT99cBZi_WJ1VmGTBc1?usp=sharing).

The full code used:

```r
# Load Package
library(ResistanceGA) 
library(rgdal)
library(corpcor)
library(pryr)

## Create Directory for Examples ##
if("ResistanceGA_Examples"%in%dir("D:/ResistanceGA/Data/Model_Outputs/100m")==FALSE)
  dir.create(file.path("D:/ResistanceGA/Data/Model_Outputs/", "100m"))

## Create Directory Object for .asc Files and results
write.dir <- "D:/ResistanceGA/Data/Model_Outputs/FINAL"

## Set working directory ##
setwd("D:/ResistanceGA/Data/Model_Ouputs/100m")

## Set ASC Directory ##
asc.dir <- "D:/ResistanceGA/Data/FINAL/100m/ASC"

## Sample locations
samples <- read.table("D:/ResistanceGA/EGK_SampleLoc.txt", sep="")
sp.dat <- SpatialPoints(samples[,c(1,2)], proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
sp.dat.reproj <- spTransform(sp.dat, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=56 +south"))

## Input Genetic Matrix ##
gen_dist <- read.table('D:/ResistanceGA/EGK_Fst.txt', sep="", header = FALSE)

## Bring in Geochemistry Rasters ##
carbon <- raster('carbon.asc')
phos <-raster('phosphorus.asc')
nit <-raster('nitrogen.asc')

## Create the Raster Stack ##
r.stack <- stack(carbon, phos, nit)

## Change Projection Of Datasets ##
crs(sp.dat.reproj)<- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=56 +south +datum=WGS84")
crs(r.stack)<- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=56 +south +datum=WGS84")

## Genetic Distance Inputs ##
gdist.inputs <- gdist.prep(length(sp.dat.reproj),
                           samples = sp.dat.reproj,
                           response = lower(as.matrix(gen_dist)),
                           method = 'commuteDistance')

GA.inputs <- GA.prep(ASCII.dir = r.stack,
                     Results.dir = write.dir,
                     parallel = 14)

SS_RESULTS.gdist <- SS_optim(gdist.inputs = gdist.inputs,
                             GA.inputs = GA.inputs)
```

Error arises when the following is run:

```
SS_RESULTS.gdist <- SS_optim(gdist.inputs = gdist.inputs,
                             GA.inputs = GA.inputs)
```

and outputs:

```
Error in { : task 5 failed - "0 (non-NA) cases"
```

When it should output iterative metrics like:

```
GA | iter = 1 | Mean = -57442.214 | Best =    155.842
GA | iter = 2 | Mean = -56714.224 | Best =    157.142
GA | iter = 3 | Mean = -28712.441 | Best =    159.342
GA | iter = 4 | Mean = -34414.224 | Best =    159.842
```

Comment: We don't have all the data needed to run this, the link only has three .ASC grid files, and the code reads in some TXT files. You're also not clear about which function on which line is generating the error. Its hard to fix code "by inspection", we really need to be able to *run* your code, and that means either having all your data that runs it, or code that generates data (eg a random set of points) that *also* create the same error.

Comment: Its also helpful if code doesn't have all your paths and folders written out every time. That means we have to edit every file path to make your code work. One tip is to specify all folders **once** at the very start (eg `datadir = "D:/foo/bar/data/"`) and then in the code get the data by constructing paths from `datadir`, eg `nit = raster(file.path(datadir,"nitro.asc"))`. This makes it much easier to work from different folders without having to hunt down every path reference somewhere in the code.

Comment: @Spacedman My apologies, I have updated the data and the code to reflect your suggestions. All of the subsequent information should be there to generate the errors now. Thanks for the suggestions, and sorry again for not being more clear!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It could be something specific to `commuteDistance`, because `costDistance` worked. I have a bunch of rasters that work for `commuteDistance`, and then one that doesn't, even though they are all the same extent (I used 'resample' relative to a raster that worked). I also checked that none of my sample points were `NA`.... no problem there...

I did eventually get this raster to work. Seems that by aggregating to low resolution before 'resample', something may have gone wrong with one of the rasters. Instead, I resampled first with the original high-resolution rasters, and then aggregated.